# Equality comparison on the output of a wstring iterator not working

Tags: c++, string, vector, equality

I've got a vector holding wstrings. I want to see if one of the strings has the same contents as a string in a variable:

```
std::wstring m_MyString;

void CheckExists() {
    std::vector< std::wstring > list = ...
    for (std::vector< std::wstring >::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == m_MyString) {
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `*it == m_MyString` doesn't seem to be doing string equality - it doesn't go into the `if` when there's a matching string in the vector. I think it's doing pointer/address equality. How do I get it to do basic string equality?

Comment: What leads you to believe it is not doing a string equality comparison?

Comment: The equality operator should work fine, but you could try [`compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) instead. Also remember that comparisons are case sensitive.

Comment: @juanchopanza because it doesn't go into the `if` when the iterator has a string with the same contents as the string in the variable.

Comment: @thecoop can you show us the exact contents of both strings?

Comment: Also: (`#include <algorithm>`) `std::vector< std::wstring >::iterator it = std::find( list.begin(), list.end(), m_MyString ); if (it != list.end()) { ... }`

Comment: It could be a problem with your `wstring`s. Try the same code with some `std:string`s and it will "work".

Comment: @Tony: the string contents of the iterator and variable in the debugger are exactly the same.

Comment: See [demo here](http://ideone.com/E8a1LW).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the string in the variable was null-terminated, the strings in the vector weren't. So they looked the same, but weren't actually the same.